# Tracking an google analytics event in an iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, google-analytics

Okay so I'm a google analytics & js noob so I know the absolute basics.

On my site http://www.wildseasonthegame.com I have some humble bundle widgets which are Iframes.

I'm still trying to understand analytics but as I understand it Theoretically I should be having a code like this

```
<a href="#" onClick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'cateogry', 'action', 'label name']);"> something goes here </a>
```

Now my question is =

1. Can I replace href with iframe and will it just work? Or will i need to do other stuff (like add some extra JS) to make it work, seeing as how iframes are funny little things
2. Or do I wrap each iframe in its own a href with a # destination and track conversions that way?
3. HOw do i differentiate between clicks made to input their email and clicks to purchase?
4. Any other suggestions how I can track the conversion offsite. Humble bundle has an off site thank you page, but It doesnt look like it redirects back to myne, let alone guarantee tha tpeople will arrive at my page instead of closing their browser after the transaction.

Answer (score 0):

If content is iFramed in you're unfortunately going to have a hard time getting any tracking on it thanks to the same-domain policy. The best way would be to add tracking code to the pages iFrame'd in... but good luck getting Humble Bundle to add your code to their pages. You can get some [click tracking](https://github.com/finalclap/iframeTracker-jquery) on it, but it'd literally just be clicks anywhere on the iFrame.

Comment: Thats what i figured, I suppose its better than nothing. Could you guide me thru what i'd need to do to handle that in my iframe code? Also would it register per click per user? or one click per user within a 10 second window counts as a conversion? (to avoid clicking once to input your mail, and once to pay by amazon or paypal, to count as 2 conversions). Or does taht happen by default?
Thanks